# I can't use gauge-solid and spline chart at the same time by using HighCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I want to use both spline and gauge-solid in same page but different DIV.

When I load both highcharts.js and highcharts-more.js and put example code nto my HTML code, I get an error in Firefox console:

> Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17

When I  go to page I get this explanation:

> Highcharts Error #17
>   The requested series type does not exist
>   This error happens when you are setting chart.type or series.type to a series type that isn't defined in Highcharts. A typical reason may be that your are missing the extension file where the series type is defined, for example in order to run an arearange series you need to load the highcharts-more.js file.

Frankly, I am not a coder, so, I cant understand it clearly. Before wrote down of code for gauge, my spline chart work correctly. It is still working. But gause charts not work.
Here is my gause chart codes:

```
...Some PHP and HTML codes here...

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="solid-gauge.js"></script>
<script src="highcharts.js"></script
$(function () {

var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// The speed gauge
$('#container_half_pie_in').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Download'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));

// The RPM gauge
$('#container_half_pie_out').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'Upload'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RPM',
        data: [1],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
        }
    }]

}));

// Bring life to the dials
setTimeout(function () {
    // Speed
    var chart = $('#container_half_pie_in').highcharts(),
        point,
        newVal,
        inc;

    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }

    // RPM
    chart = $('#container_half_pie_out').highcharts();
    if (chart) {
        point = chart.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }
}, 2000);


})

            <div id="half_pies" class="row">
            <div class="col s12 m6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div id="container_half_pie_in" style=" margin: 0 auto">dsd</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col s12 m6">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div id="container_half_pie_out" style=" margin: 0 auto">dsd </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-action"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...Some PHP and HTML codes here...
```

What should I do?
 Regards,

Comment: can you provide a JSFiddle so we can have a look at a live example of what you have so far?

Comment: Hi, It looks like you have problems with your scripts. Are you sure that you have loaded correct scripts? You may try to change the order of this scripts, so highcharts.js will be added just after jQuery.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tceydeliler/uqaLdwLa/3/   I try that. But nothing changes. It is  about series. but I dont know what the error talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED,
My charts have problem because of wrong path of highcarts-more.js
I check it , now works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved Using this code..
Copy and paste and It gonna work!

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 400px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
<div id="hola" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
Highcharts.chart('hola', {
    chart: {
        type: 'spline'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
            'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature'
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                return this.value + '°';
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        crosshairs: true,
        shared: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        spline: {
            marker: {
                radius: 4,
                lineColor: '#666666',
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        },
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, {
            y: 26.5,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/sun.png)'
            }
        }, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        marker: {
            symbol: 'diamond'
        },
        data: [{
            y: 3.9,
            marker: {
                symbol: 'url(https://www.highcharts.com/samples/graphics/snow.png)'
            }
        }, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
    }]
});
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        type: 'gauge',
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBackgroundImage: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 0,
        plotShadow: false
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Speedometer'
    },

    pane: {
        startAngle: -150,
        endAngle: 150,
        background: [{
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#FFF'],
                    [1, '#333']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '109%'
        }, {
            backgroundColor: {
                linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1 },
                stops: [
                    [0, '#333'],
                    [1, '#FFF']
                ]
            },
            borderWidth: 1,
            outerRadius: '107%'
        }, {
            // default background
        }, {
            backgroundColor: '#DDD',
            borderWidth: 0,
            outerRadius: '105%',
            innerRadius: '103%'
        }]
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,

        minorTickInterval: 'auto',
        minorTickWidth: 1,
        minorTickLength: 10,
        minorTickPosition: 'inside',
        minorTickColor: '#666',

        tickPixelInterval: 30,
        tickWidth: 2,
        tickPosition: 'inside',
        tickLength: 10,
        tickColor: '#666',
        labels: {
            step: 2,
            rotation: 'auto'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'km/h'
        },
        plotBands: [{
            from: 0,
            to: 120,
            color: '#55BF3B' // green
        }, {
            from: 120,
            to: 160,
            color: '#DDDF0D' // yellow
        }, {
            from: 160,
            to: 200,
            color: '#DF5353' // red
        }]
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

},
// Add some life
function (chart) {
    if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
        setInterval(function () {
            var point = chart.series[0].points[0],
                newVal,
                inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 20);

            newVal = point.y + inc;
            if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
                newVal = point.y - inc;
            }

            point.update(newVal);

        }, 3000);
    }
});
</script>
```